# Como enviar array de dados para a controller asp.net core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-core

Tenho uma tela onde tenho o cadastro de alguns itens, no meu controle estou recendo os dados do array, mais está vindo vazio.

Já testei algumas opções aqui do fórum, como “JSON.stringify” e “JSON.parse”.

Imagem da leitura dos dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no meu controller, estou recebendo os dados assim:

```
public IActionResult SaveOrder( string[] order)
{
    string result =  order.ToString();
    return Json(result);
}
```

```js
  <script>

        function ExibirModalNovoProduto() {
            $("#ModalNovoProduto").modal('show');
        };

        // Adicionar pedido
        $("#addToList").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($.trim($("#productName").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#price").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#quantity").val()) == "") return;

            var productName = $("#productName").val(),
                price = $("#price").val(),
                quantity = $("#quantity").val(),
                detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");

            var productItem = '<tr><td>' + productName + '</td><td>' + quantity + '</td><td>' + price + '</td><td>' + (parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity)) + '</td><td><a data-itemId="0" href="#" class="deleteItem">Remove</a></td></tr>';
            detailsTableBody.append(productItem);
            clearItem();
        });

        // Após adicionar um novo pedido na lista, limpar o formulário para Adicionar mais pedidos.
        function clearItem() {
            $("#productName").val('');
            $("#price").val('');
            $("#quantity").val('');
        };

          // Depois de adicionar um novo pedido à lista, se desejar, você pode removê-lo.
        $(document).on('click', 'a.deleteItem', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $self = $(this);
            if ($(this).attr('data-itemId') == "0") {
                $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "#ff6347").fadeOut(800, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });

         // Coletar lista de pedidos múltiplos para o passe ao controlador
        $("#saveOrder").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var orderArr = [];
            orderArr.length = 0;

            $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {
                orderArr.push({
                    productName: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                    quantity: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                    price: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                    amount: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()
                });
            });


        var dadosrecebido = JSON.stringify({
            name: $("#name").val(),
            address: $("#address").val(),
            order: orderArr
        });

            $.when(saveOrder(data)).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
 
        });

    // Após clicar no botão Salvar, passe toda a exibição de dados para o controlador para salvar o banco de dados
    function saveOrder(dadosrecebido) {
        console.log(dadosrecebido);
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Orders/SaveOrder/?registros=" + dadosrecebido,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        });
    };

    </script>
```

Resultado final;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite.
Efetue essas mudanças e vá testando uma por uma até funcionar:
1. Ao enviar o data, não envie como "JSON.stringify({ data })", retire os "{}", ficara como "JSON.stringify(data)", tenho certeza que é isso.
2. Serialize o JSON para uma variável antes de efetuar o POST.
3. Sua controller vai receber um json único para deserializar lá, então troque o array de string "string[] order" por "string order", dessa forma você remove o código redundante.

Comment: Agora é mais uma dica mano... O post não retorna resultado, ele só retorna um 200 ou 404... Se a sua requisição espera algo em troca ela é get.

Comment: Pegando meio no pé agora... Leia imediatamente essa página da wikipedia sobre o protocolo Http: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: tentei muitas opções e não tive sucesso, vou continuar tentando uma solução

Comment: Se quiser me passar seu discord você transmite tua tela e eu te ajudo.

Comment: o meu é itasouza#6189, agradeço

Comment: com sua ajuda tudo deu certo, já adicionei um resposta positiva

Comment: Ai sim man! Só dá uma olhada em como o razor funciona... O ajax não é necessário quando se usa o asp .net.